# For loop in twig using variables

Tags: twig, templating

im trying to go through a loop multiple times and I want to use my variable to determine how many times the loop will be executed. But I cannot get it to work.
Im fairly new to Twig.

```
{% for item in items %}
    {% for i in 1..item.content %}
        <div>{{ item.content }}</div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

**EDIT:**
No clue what Im doing wrong. When I print `item.content` like this `{{ item.content }}` it outputs `5`. But when I go trough the loop like in [this example](https://twigfiddle.com/zj6vit), I only get the result once

Comment: Unsure what you're trying there, but if want you to know how many time the loop is executed you'd go with `{{ items|length }}`

Comment: I just want a simple for loop. This is the php version of what I want to achieve: `for($i = 0; $i < item.content; $i++) { do_something }`
item.content equals an integer.

Comment: But `item.content` is a `string`?

Comment: It is ? Well as I said Im new to twig. `item.content` contains `5`. Cant I use that to create a loop ?

Comment: You can, but the output would meaningless as seen [here](https://twigfiddle.com/zj6vit). What is your desired output?

Comment: No clue what Im doing wrong. When I print `item.content` like this `{{ item.content }}` it outputs `5`. But when I go trough the loop like in your example, I only get the result once.